# remove quantity column from checkout onepage page from order review step

Tags: onepage-checkout

I am trying to remove quantity column from order review step on `checkout/onepage` page but it removing only heading not data.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow below steps:

**Step : 1**

Remove quantity column from the file

```
\template\checkout\onepage\review\info.phtml
```

**Step : 2**

Remove data from the file

```
\template\checkout\onepage\review\item.phtml


<td class="a-center"><?php echo $_item->getQty() ?></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove it from

```
app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml
```

remove below code from file

```
<td class="a-center"><?php echo $_item->getQty() ?></td>
```

If this file is called from base you will need to put it in your theme.